# Linq to XML -I can do it with listbox but not with a List<>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is how I form my xml from a ListBox

```
   new XElement("City", lstCities.Items
                            .Cast<ListItem>()
                            .Select(x => new XElement("TBL_Cities", 
                                new XElement ("CityName",x.Text),
                                new XElement("TripID",TripID)))
```

Now maybe its because its close to the end of day, but I can't figure out how to do it with a List<> I have (Its  List lstImages) I basically want to write the byte file to xml, like cities (as there are 1-3 images within the list)

Here is the part that isn't working

```
new XElement("TBL_Photo",lstImages
                                .Cast<byte>()
                                .Select(x => new XElement("TBL_Photo", 
                                    new XElement ("Photo",x),
                                    new XElement("TripID",TripID))))
```

Comment: Can you post the variation of the code that _does not_ work, but that you're trying to get to.

Comment: okay, made the edit. this should be grabbing the byte information for each lstImage item

Comment: Also, how is it "not working" - syntax error?  runtime error?

Comment: Please elaborate on "isn't working". Throwing an error? Producing incorrect output? Producing **no** output? ...

Comment: Should've said wasn't sure about. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code against the `List<byte>` is mostly correct. You have an unnecessary call to `.Cast` (but it won't break anything). Your chief problem appears to be one too many closing parentheses, unless there is more code you are not showing us.

```
new XElement("TBL_Photo",
     lstImages.Select(x => new XElement("TBL_Photo",  
                  new XElement ("Photo",x), 
                  new XElement("TripID",TripID)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on how listImages is defined, but assuming that it is a `List<List<byte>>`, then just

```
  new XElement("TBL_Photo",lstImages 
                //.Cast<byte>()  Not needed
                .Select(x => new XElement("TBL_Photo",  
                    new XElement ("Photo",x), 
                    new XElement("TripID",TripID))))
```

This assumes that XElement permits List as a parameter.

You don't need the cast here. You only need it because lstCities.Items was a ListItemCollection, which does not implement `IEnumerable<ListItem>`.